# Did Western "New Imperialism" actually free slaves in Muslim lands?

Tags: slavery, colonization, islam, imperialism

[Slavery is fair game in mainstream/traditional Islam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_views_on_slavery). I have heard various commentaries that abolishing of slavery in various Muslim-dominated countries actually coincided with the 2nd wave of Western colonialism (19th century on).

I the particular area is North Africa.

Is that true -- did slavery as an economic system/alternative get abolished in North Africa only when the Europeans started colonizing it?

Comment: Quite possible - as those slaves were often kidnapped Europeans

Comment: I was told they were often subsaharan africans

Comment: Slavery was also fair game in Christianity until the mid 1700s

Comment: That's absolutely correct. Slavery within islam was (grudgingly) abolished because Europeans demanded it.

Comment: @amphibient both sub Saharan blacks and Europeans were commonly used as slaves by muslims in both north Africa and elsewhere, with Europeans more seen in northern Africa and blacks more in east Africa and the middle east (logistics played a larger role in that than anything probably).

Comment: @ClintEastwood and in islam even today. Many "guest workers" in islamic countries are little more than slaves.

Comment: @jwenting It would be naive (let's give you the benefit of doubt) to think that [migrants are abused only in Islamic countries](https://www.japantimes.co.jp/news/2018/01/02/national/abuses-still-abound-labor-strapped-japans-foreign-trainee-worker-system/#.W0S3VU2buUk), and trying to characterize it [as a problem that only affects "them"](https://www.thestar.com/news/canada/migrants/2017/10/07/this-sexually-abused-migrant-worker-is-now-safe-but-she-knows-others-arent.html) seems to be [rather missinformed](https://edition.cnn.com/2018/01/23/asia/hrw-thailand-fishing-reform-report/index.html).

Comment: Of course, that does not mean that every country is the same, and countries where racism is more prevalent and where immigrants are viewed with hostility and/or fear, and with a higher corruption level, give abusers a higher degree of impunity.

Comment: @SJuan76 sure, not just guest workers are abused in muslim countries, locals are too, especially women and those who aren't muslims. But guest workers who have to surrender their passports and visum documents to their employers, live in closed compounds they're not allowed to leave, and have most of their salary docked as payment for "accommodation and food" they could obtain cheaper elsewhere, is effectively slavery. I'm not talking just about the physical and sexual abuse of domestic servants in arab countries.

Comment: My reading has only touched on this, but I can tell you with certainty that individual European colonialists, such as Charles Gordon, were strongly motivated by anti-slavery convictions. But how those individuals fit into the big picture of European colonialism in North Africa is not a question I'm prepared or able to answer.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_George_Gordon

Comment: jwenting, there are slaves in Mauritania today. It was outlawed recently but nobody enforces the law. There are living people which were enslaved in Sudan. The Islamic State also justify its slaves (specially sexual slaves) by islamic jurisprudence. Look for complete quotes about islamic law in Robert Spencer Jihad Watch page. More directly, babary pirates did not stop taking european slaves until french conquest. Look to the American Barbary Coast Wars, the americans were the first to go there in arms to stop ship raids.

Answer (score 1):

There is at least a kernel of truth here for sure. [Here](http://autocww.colorado.edu/~toldy2/E64ContentFiles/AfricanHistory/SlaveryInAfrica.html) is a relevant article which described Europe's role in the gradual decline of slavery in Africa:

> Although colonial authorities began outlawing slavery in some African
>   territories as early as the 1830s, the complete legal abolition of
>   slavery in Africa did not take place until the first quarter of the
>   20th century. By that time, however, slavery was deeply ingrained in
>   most African societies, and thus the practice continued illegally.
>   **Slaves who became liberated often did so by escaping and going to the
>   colonial authorities** or by simply leaving the areas in which they had
>   been held to take up residence elsewhere. In some places, enslaved
>   persons held that status throughout their lives, despite the legal
>   prohibition. It was not until the 1930s that slavery in Africa was
>   almost totally eliminated.

However the role of European colonial powers in ending slavery, relative to other factors, should not be over-emphasized. As the Wikipedia article on [slavery in the Muslim world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_slavery_in_the_Muslim_world) puts it:

> Throughout the 19th and 20th centuries, slavery gradually became
>   outlawed and suppressed in Muslim lands, **due to a combination of
>   pressure** exerted by Western nations such as Britain and France,
>   internal pressure from Islamic abolitionist movements, and economic
>   pressures.

A key episode in the early part of this process was in the 1830s when the [Barbary slave trade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbary_slave_trade) was ended as a result of the [French colonization of Algeria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_conquest_of_Algeria).  But for about two centuries prior to this, Europeans played the most pivotal role in driving the expansion of [the much larger slave trade in West Africa and the Atlantic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlantic_slave_trade).

Comment: I dispute your statement "*the much larger slave trade in West Africa and the Atlantic*", from your own link: "*Four million enslaved people exported via the Red Sea, another four million[18] through the Swahili ports of the Indian Ocean, perhaps as many as nine million along the trans-Saharan caravan route, and eleven to twenty million (depending on the author) across the Atlantic Ocean*" That's about 17 million vs something between 11 and 20 million. Those are comparable numbers, neither **much larger** than the other.

Comment: That quote covers a much longer period (1,000 years vs 200) and doesn't even seem to include the Barbary trade at all, which went through the Mediterranean and totaled something closer to 1 million.

Answer (score 1):

DOCTOR THOMAS SOWELL, in his very illuminating book "BLACK REDNECKS & WHITE LIBERALS" wrote a chapter, "The Real History of Slavery", in which he described the significant efforts of the British, the Royal Navy, etc., to interdict, disrupt, stop slavery, & to free slaves, in their colonized lands around the world.

It’s been a few years since I read this book, so I can’t provide quotes or anything more at this time except to say that it mentioned a number of lands on the African continent, and this would include some Muslim areas.  So I commend it for your research.

This was rarely recognized fact was done, of course, after their well-known long record to profit by the Slave Trade.   I also suggest you might look into England’s SLAVERY ABOLITION ACT of 1833, and the years following.  That act abolished slavery throughout the British Empire; and strenuous efforts were made to enforce it in its colonies.